# ValueError at /studentform/ ModelForm has no model class specified

Tags: python, django

I am getting an error while running the following form. please help me to fix the error.

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.
class student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    emailid = models.EmailField(max_length=60)
    marks = models.CharField(max_length=11)
    date = models.DateTimeField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from .models import *

class student_form(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(), required=True, max_length=100)
    emailid = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.EmailField(), required=True)


class Meta():
    model = student
    fields = ['name','emailiid']
```

I have tried many things but no solution. please look at in this code and help to sort this out. so confusing for me as i am new to Django.

Comment: What is the error? You need to provide the full traceback.  (ps: I'm assuming the Meta class is correctly indented in your code..?)

Comment: The `Meta` class is part of the `student_form` class  (so a `class` *in* a `class`).

Answer (score 2):

In `forms.py`, you must indent the `Meta` class so it is part of the `student_form` class.

This gives:

```
from django import forms
from .models import *

class student_form(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(), required=True, max_length=100)
    emailid = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.EmailField(), required=True)


    class Meta:
        model = student
        fields = ['name','emailiid']
```

Comment: thanks for the solution. i tried class Meta: like this before but didn't work. The real problem was i was not giving spaces before writing class Meta: this is what i realized when i look at your code. Thanks.